# Flatten Spark Dataframe and Name Columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

How can one unnest an array within a spark dataframe, such that the resulting dataframe contains one row for each value in the original array?

Example:

```
scala> df.show()
+---------+------+
|employees|person|
+---------+------+
|[1, 2, 3]|  Mary|
|[4, 5, 6]|  John|
+---------+------+
```

Expected result:

```
+---------+------+
|employee |person|
+---------+------+
|1        |  Mary|
|2        |  Mary|
|3        |  Mary|
|4        |  John|
|5        |  John|
|6        |  John|
+---------+------+
```

This is what I have tried:

```
df.select($"person", explode($"employees")).show()

+------+---+
|person|col|
+------+---+
|  Mary|  1|
|  Mary|  2|
|  Mary|  3|
|  John|  4|
|  John|  5|
|  John|  6|
+------+---+
```

How can I have the resulting exploded column be named "employee"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I have the resulting exploded column be named "employee"?

```
df.select($"person", explode($"employees").alias("employee")).show()
```

or

```
df.select($"person", explode($"employees").as("employee")).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `withColumn` as to create a new column as

```
df.withColumn("employee", explode($"employees")).show()
```